# PostgreSQL - return multiple rows as one

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that returns two rows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT cola,colb from table LIMIT 2
) as f
```

Result is:

```
cola, colb
x, 1
y, 2
```

Is it possible to use  the results in the top level SELECT? Similar to:

```
SELECT some_function(x,y), some_other_function(1,2) 
FROM (
  SELECT cola,colb from table LIMIT 2
) as f
```

Here is the actual query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      alt, 
      st_distance_sphere(
        st_closestpoint(geom,st_setsrid(st_makepoint(x,y),4326)),
        st_setsrid(st_makepoint(x,y),4326)
      ) as d
    FROM table
) as foo
```

It returns:

```
alt | d
800 | 9.658
900 | 11.59
etc
```

Comment: You can't use the values retrieved in the subquery as fieldnames in the parent query. SQL doesn't work that way. You COULD retrieve those values and build a new query from them, but there's no automatic way to do what you want.

Comment: I assume it's something similar to cola[0] etc. I haven't been able to see anything about this online (maybe I'm searching for the wrong terminology?) so posted here looking for help... ?

Comment: Hmm...Are the IDs to which x and y, 1 and 2 belong the same? If so, then this could probably be done with a pivot solution.

Comment: @JaazCole - they are not (I think you are asking if they have a key?).  The initial query is actually a PostGIS spatial calculation that uses data passed to the query and not a table.

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of cross-tabulation to aggregate multiple rows into one.

Your example would work like this:

```
SELECT some_function(arr_a[1], arr_a[2])
     , some_other_function(arr_b[1], arr_b[2]) 
FROM (
   SELECT array_agg(cola) AS arr_a
        , array_agg(colb) AS arr_b
   FROM   (
      SELECT cola, colb
      FROM   tbl
      ORDER  BY cola
      LIMIT  2
      ) sub1
   ) sub2;
```

There are various ways. Depends on your *actual* problem.